# Generate, then order random numbers in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

So I'm using SQL to build a database of math questions.

My typical query might look something like this:

```
SELECT @num1 := FLOOR(Rand()*8 + 2),@num2 := FLOOR(Rand()*8 + 2);
    INSERT INTO `QuestionDB`(TopicID, TopicName, SubtopicID, SubtopicName, Question, Answer, Difficulty, Author, Projectable) VALUES (3,"Multiplying",1,"Multiplying single digit numbers",CONCAT(@num1, " &times; ", @num2 ,"= "),@num1*@num2,1,"Me","Yes");
```

I'm using PHPMyAdmin to do this and build up my database.

This works fine. However, what I would like to do is this, so that I can order numbers ie:

```
SELECT @num1 := FLOOR(Rand()),@num2 := FLOOR(Rand()),@num3 := FLOOR(Rand()),@num4 := FLOOR(Rand());
    INSERT INTO `QuestionDB`(TopicID, TopicName, SubtopicID, SubtopicName, Question, Answer, Difficulty, Author, Projectable) VALUES (7,"Ordering",1,"Ordering whole numbers",CONCAT("<span class='smaller'>Order, from highest to lowest</span><br>", @num1, " , ", @num2, etc),ORDER_ASS(@num1,@num2,@num3,@num4),1,"Me","Yes");
```

However, obviously ORDER_ASS isn't a valid SQL function. Is there an SQL function that will do this?

Comment: Sample data and desired results *in a tabular format in the question* would really help.  Assigning values to variables to use in a `SELECT` is indirect, so say the least.

Comment: Sorry. I'm not quite sure what you mean, a tabular format

I don't have any sample data, as I want to generate my numbers randomly. So I want to generate 4 random numbers, then place them, in order in a column called 'answer'

Comment: my suggestion is that to insert numbers to temp table, then sort the numbers by  (select num from temp_table order by num desc) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sorting-rows.html

Comment: is the issue here that I'm trying to do something SQL simply wasn't designed to do? I suspect I am better off writing a PHP script and running that